# How can I apply UIColor to an existing image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uicolor

I have `a1.png` image. 
I want to apply a color effect on that image.
By "apply a colour" I mean a foreground color with alpha < 1.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: what do you mean with "apply any color"? do you mean a foreground color with alpha < 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't get solution for applying UIColor to existing image.

One alternative way is that instead of applying color to an image you can take a View and apply color to the view.

```
UIColor *color = [del color];

[perceptView setBackgroundColor:[color colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];

[perceptView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [GLImageProcessing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code

Comment: hello saqib. i have seen GLimageProcessing. But that doesn't help me. i want to set particular color to any normal image.

Comment: why dont you add UIImageView on top of your image and play with its aplha and color value?